# access google machine learning API from another API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth, google-cloud-ml

I created a custom tensorflow model and deployed to google cloud AI platform. To access the online prediction at (https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project/models/my-model/versions/my-version:predict),
I can use default auth token got with the following command:

`access_token=$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)`

or, according to: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/python-client-library, I can create a service account key, download it, and use it to in an outh2 authentication protocol.

The problem arises when I want to access the online prediction from another API that I am deploying in Google Cloud Platform: in this case the command above doesn't work and I can't access to any file to sign my jwt for authentication. How can I create my jwt without accessing to any file?

Comment: Since applications use [service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) to make authorized API calls. You will most likely need to authorize the calling service account from the receiving application. So, if you are working with Google Cloud Platform, unless you plan to build your own client library, use service accounts and a Cloud Client Library instead of performing authorization explicitly as described in this [document](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount?_ga=2.231986140.-21198433.1566303427#authorizingrequests).

Comment: Your answer is clear but, as I explained in the question, Google Cloud Client library requires to access to service account infos (in particular to the private key to sign the jwt) present in a file that you are required to download; this can't be done in the API that I would deploy. I'm looking for a procedure by which I can require the json file associated with the service account, decode it and use it to create the jwt for authentication.

Comment: In any case, I would download your service account credentials into your local environment from a Cloud Storage bucket. Then, I would insert the downloaded file path in `SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE` variable, as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount?_ga=2.231986140.-21198433.1566303427#authorizingrequests). Lastly, I would use the created `credentials` object to call Google APIs by using the following [code sample](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount?_ga=2.231986140.-21198433.1566303427#callinganapi). Keep me posted.

Comment: I also thought to a similar solution. For the moment I have saved the private key associated with the service account in a dictionary that then I pass to the function google.auth.crypt.RSASigner.from_service_account_info (my_dictionary)

Comment: I can see that you are following the [Making an authenticated request to an Endpoints API](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/service-account-authentication#making_an_authenticated_request) documentation, correct? For more info about the [Receiving authentication details in your API](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/service-account-authentication#receiving_authentication_details_in_your_api) follow the link. Let me know if this helps you.